# Finding repeating numbers above or below 1, in an array

Tags: c#, comparison, iteration

I need to find out how many times the number greater than or less than `1` appears in the array.

For example, if I have an array:

```
{1,1,1,2,3,-18,45,1}
```

here numbers that are greater than or less than one appear just once

Another example, if I have an array

```
{1,1,1,2,3,-18,45,1,0}
```

here numbers that are greater than or less than one appear twice, that is at the second to last there is a `1` and after that there is a `0`

One more example

```
{1,1,2,3,1,-18,26,1}
```

here numbers that are greater than or less than one appear twice, one set is `{2,3}` thats once and another set is `{-18,26}` so thats twice.

So far ive been able to loop the array but im stuck .. how to do this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(isOneBalanced(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, -18, 45, 1 }));
    }

    static int isOneBalanced(int[] a)
    {
        foreach(int a1 in a)
        {

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

how to do this can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you reword this "if i have an array {1,1,1,2,3,-18,45,1} here numbers that are greater than or less than one appears just once" I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: what i meant is that the group of number that is between 1s appears just once i.e if the array was {1,1,2,3,1,4,5,1} then since {2,3} and {4,5} appears between 1s then it should be counted as two times

Comment: Basically, you need to count the number of sequences within the array where each item is not 1. Is this correct? If so, Alan's answer is correct (at least when he removes mention of -1, as I noted).

Comment: urm... i didn't quite get the answer tha alan gave , i mean ok we can set a boolean value to see if we are in non 1 series but how can we count the whole non 1 series as 1

Comment: @Jarus: That's not exactly what he meant by the boolean value.  The value determines whether you've already incremented your counter for this particular non-1 series...so you make sure to add it once, but only once.  You can see my answer below for some additional details on this, but Alan is pretty close in basics (I think only his bit on the "-1" strikes me as wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay...in a nutshell you want to iterate over this loop once, figure out when you're "between 1's", and increment a counter.

There's an additional trick or two, though...one "trick" is that you should pay special attention to keeping track of whether you've already incremented for a particular set or not.  If your series is {1, 3, 5, 1}, you don't want to do something like:

```
1: don't increment 
3: increment
5: increment       // this is bad!
1: don't increment
```

because you'll end up with 2, instead of 1.  So keep track of whether you've already incremented with a boolean...call it something like "haveIncremented", and you'll end up with a line like:

```
// if (haveIncremented is false)
    // increment my counter
    // set haveIncremented to true
```

Then, of course, you'll need to make sure that you set haveIncremented set back to false again, when you start a new set.  This will happen when you read in a new "1", and are now ready to start a new "set".

I'm trying to walk a fine line between coding and explaining and helping.  Hopefully this will help while not giving away the whole farm.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks Beska i got it now , thanks for explaining it to me in detail 
=)

Answer (score 2):

[Iterate through the array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3zzhdw(VS.80).aspx) in a foreach loop, and [test each value against 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). If it's less than 1, increment num_greater by 1, and if it's less, increment nun_less by 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Create variables to be used throughout 
   the process */
int counter = 0;
bool newgroup = true;

/* For each array entry: this loop will
   cycle through our array, accessing one
   item at a time and refer to it as 'a1' */
foreach(int a1 in a) 
{
  /* If 'a1' (our current array entry) is
     absolutely equal to 1, set the value
     of our boolean variable to true */
  if(a1 == 1)   
    newgroup = true;
  else 
  {
    /* Else (meaning, a1 isn't equal to 1), 
       if our variable 'newgroup' is true
       increment our counter variable by 1
       and set our boolean variable to false */
    if(newgroup)
    {
      counter++;    
      newgroup = false;
    }
  }
}    
return counter;
```

Comment: @Beska: Since he is studying for an exam, a code answer is not necessarily a bad thing...though it's not nearly as helpful as an explanation.

Comment: (To either the poster, or someone with high enough privs to do so...this would be much more helpful with some comments...the variable names are good, but the concept may still go down a bit easier with some additional commentary about the "what you're doing")

Answer (score 0):

You need two variables. One is a boolean, and is used to keep track of whether you are in a series of numbers which are not equal to 1 or -1. The other is an integer, and is used to keep track of the total number of series you encounter.

Comment: This answer seems the most correct, but I didn't see anything about comparing with -1 in the question, so you should likely remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a boolean to determine if 1 was the previous value and a integer to count the number of times you don't see a 1 when the boolean is set.

Answer (score 0):

This could be seen as a finite state machine problem with a sequence of inputs... keep track of your state when you iterate through, and updating your state based on the current value of the array.  For instance, one of the states could be responsible for incrementing your bounded elements counter.  This should be easy to figure out if you diagram it on a piece of paper... circles for states, and arrows linking states based on the type of input you see.

Good luck!